# Putting all-screen-sizing image as background in custom element

Tags: html, css

Hopefully this will be a quick question. I wanted to add an image to my landing page that scales to any screen. I found this code to be the suggested and most optimal method

```
html {
  background: url('image/img.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; }
```

However I am having problems implementing this. This code does what it is supposed to, however if I set it under html then this image takes place anywhere I call html in my site which I dont want. I want this to occur in one page of my site only. I tried creating my own custom html tag bodycover {} but that didn't work.

I am new to this and have not taken a step into custom html tags yet. I feel like there is an easy solution to this but I can't find it despite researching it thoroughly.

Thanks

EDIT: If there is a simply way to get this working without a custom element that would be even better. I simply don't know of one

Comment: Why does this need to be a custom element? Why not use a div?

Comment: If div works that would be way better but I couldn't get that working either

Answer (score 0):

Like @Paulie_D said, you don't need to apply this to the `html` tag; a standard `div` will work. Also, give the new element some dimension to width and height. Slightly cleaned up:

```
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('image/img.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover; 
}
```

Make sure the parent element of `.bg` has a height and width of 100% as well.

Comment: Awesome I now know how to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do like this, where you add an attribute or class to the body for the particular page.

This can be done either server side, using i.e. ASP or PHP, or client side, in the page load event.

Page to show

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.big-bkg {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<body class="big-bkg">
</body>
```

Page to not show

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.big-bkg {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah! Similar to the other comments. That worked 100% thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say: put all that stuff into `body`, not `html`

```
body {
  background: url('image/img.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with a simple absolute div with width and height 100% just after the body tag and z-index lower than the main-container.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="main-container"></div>
```